# Does Static Ip address assigned to my NUC in one network changes when I change the network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ipv4, static-ip

I bought a NUC on eBay, but I don't have a monitor. So I'm visiting my friend's place to use his TV as a monitor to install Proximox. I'm planning to assign a static IP to access the Proximox console and after the installation, come back to my home and then continue with the lab setup.

Can I access the assigned IP from my home network?

Comment: The internal IP range of the new network (where you are moving to) is likely not the same, so the addressing will need to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need an IP that fits within your network range.
Meaning that if your network is `192.168.1.x` while you friend's is
`192.168.0.x`, then you have a problem, as it's possible that after
setting an IP compatible with your network, you will lose contact with
the device at your friend's (although the setting might stick).

If the networks have compatible ranges, then there is no problem.
Use however an IP that is not used by the DHCP server, or is numerically
high, so that you may reduce the DHCP server's range to never conflict
with the device.

Comment: My home network IP range is 10.0.0.0/24. So if I set up my NUC in this range regardless of my friend's IP range, will it work? I'll have a display at my friend's place. so, connecting over the network is not needed.

Comment: It should work. Use an IP like `10.0.0.200`, meaning out of the way.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Yeah. I was just wanna try that and then tick it. It worked. Thank You.